# Error when implementing a typeclass instance for a function

Tags: haskell, typeclass

From Hutton's [https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/monparsing.pdf](https://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/monparsing.pdf)

```hs
class HuttonMonad m where
    result :: a -> m a
    bind   :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]

instance HuttonMonad Parser where
    result v = \input -> [(v, input)]
    bind p f = \inp -> concat  [ f v out | (v, out) <- p inp]
```

`ghc` brings up the following error message

```
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o ) [Source file changed]

test.hs:7:10: error: [GHC-27346]
    • The type synonym ‘Parser’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none
    • In the instance declaration for ‘HuttonMonad Parser’
  |
7 | instance HuttonMonad Parser where
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I assume Haskell has changed over the years, but how do I implement `HuttonMonad` for the `Parser` type?

(Note: I am aware of `parsec` et. al. My goal here is to follow the linked PDF)

Comment: Type synonyms cannot be partially applied. Use `newtype`.

Comment: You need `newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a, String)])`. Modify your functions so to wrap/unwrap the constructor.

Comment: Thanks! That works, but leads to somewhat awkward wrapping / unwrapping like `  plus (Parser p) (Parser q) = Parser (\inp -> (p inp ++ q inp))` Is there some Haskell magic for that?

Comment: Note that the article explicitly says that it is using Gofer, not Haskell. As far as I know they are related languages, but have never been identical.